# cannot get two inputs in brainf**k

Tags: c, brainfuck

So for some reason, when trying to get two different inputs in brainf**k, It only prompts me for one, then quits. I am trying to make something that takes two numbers and adds them, here is the code:

```
,      
>      
,   
[ 
    <     
    +      
    >    
    -    
]     
<
------------------------------------------------
.
```

And here is my interpreter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ARRAYSIZE 16777216
#define MAXCODESIZE 65536

int stack[MAXCODESIZE], stackp;
char code[MAXCODESIZE]; int codep, codelength;
short int array[ARRAYSIZE]; int memp;
int targets[MAXCODESIZE];
int c;
FILE *prog;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if (argc > 2) fprintf(stderr, "Too many arguments.\n"), exit(1);
    if (argc < 2) fprintf(stderr, "Usage: brain <file>\n"), exit(1);
    if(!(prog = fopen(argv[1], "r"))) fprintf(stderr,"Can't open the file %s.\n", argv[1]),exit(1);
    codelength = fread(code, 1, MAXCODESIZE, prog);
    fclose(prog);
    for(codep=0; codep<codelength; codep++){
        if (code[codep]=='[') stack[stackp++]=codep;
        if (code[codep]==']'){ 
            if(stackp==0){ 
                fprintf(stderr,"Unmatched ']' at byte %d.", codep), exit(1);
            } else {
                --stackp; 
                targets[codep]=stack[stackp]; 
                targets[stack[stackp]]=codep; 
            }
        }
    }
    if(stackp>0){ 
        fprintf(stderr,"Unmatched '[' at byte %d.", stack[--stackp]), exit(1);
    }
    for(codep=0;codep<codelength;codep++){
         switch(code[codep]){
            case '+': array[memp]++; break;
            case '-': array[memp]--; break;
            case '<': memp--; break;
            case '>': memp++; break;
            case ',': if((c=getchar())!=EOF) array[memp]=c=='\n'?10:c; break;
            case '.': putchar(array[memp]==10?'\n':array[memp]); fflush(stdout); break;
            case '[': if(!array[memp]) codep=targets[codep]; break;
            case ']': if(array[memp]) codep=targets[codep]; break;
        }
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

I copied it from github, so it may not be perfect, so any ideas how to fix this??

Really appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Your second `getchar()` will get the `\n` out of the buffer and thus won't wait for user input. You should consume both.

Answer (score 0):

I can't verify the interpreter, but if you use my [brainfuck interpreter](https://repl.it/@Stan085/interpreter-and-transformer-for-BrainF), and the following code:

```
-----------[+++++++++++>,----------]+[-<]
```

It should work, if you are wondering why it automatically "presses ENTER", it's because I used the `getkey` module, and if you need an explanation:

```
set block 0 to -11
it enters a loop
  adds 11 (first time = block == 0, after, char value is one above, fixed in the next loop)
  moves over and fetches input
  subtracts 10
it exits the loop IF the value is 0
adds 1
enters loop
  subtracts one, than moves over
exits loop
```